# Android NFC Techs

Tags: android, nfc

Could anyone explain to me why the supported tag technologies of an Android application are declared BOTH programmatically and in a XML file? In all examples I've seen so far it's like that. Take a look at this tutorial for example: http://mifareclassicdetectiononandroid.blogspot.com/2011/04/reading-mifare-classic-1k-from-android.html

Code:

```
mTechLists = new String[][] { new String[] { MifareClassic.class.getName() } };
```

XML file:

```
<resources xmlns:xliff="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2">
    <tech-list> 
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.NfcA</tech> 
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.MifareClassic</tech> 
    </tech-list>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 1):

They achieve different things. The technologies you specify in the XML file act as an intent filter for your Activity. That is, if the filter matches, your Activity will be launched. However, there may be more activities that match the filter, and in that case the user will need to choose an application to handle the tag.

The technologies you set programmatically using `enableForegroundDispatch()` can be used to bypass other applications; if your Activity is in the foreground, you can tell the NFC service to send all NFC tags that match the filter to your activity. So even if another Activity has exactly the same filter, the application chooser will not come up, and the Intent will go straight to your activity.

In most applications, you'll want both - it's annoying if the Activity chooser comes up whenever you scan a tag in your application. Make sure to make the filter accurate though - do not filter for things you are not interested in.